# Is every normed vector space, an inner product space

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be a vector space over  $\mathbb{C}$. If $V$ is an inner product space, then $V$  is normed (where the norm is defined as $\|x\|=\sqrt{(x,x)}$ ). Now if $V$ is normed, does it follow that $V$ is an inner product space ? I suspect no. I would like to see an example.

Thank you.

---

After reading my question again, I think it needs some clarification:

Suppose that $V$ is normed with norm $\|\ \|$. Can $V$ be given an inner product space structure such that $(x,x)=\|x\|^2$ ?

Comment: No. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law?rq=1).

Comment: @DavidMitra  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For an example of a norm that is not induced by an inner product, consider Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$ (where $n\ge 2$) with the norm $$\lVert \vec x\rVert_1:=\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|.$$

Comment: Is it clear that no inner product induces this norm ? I don't see it immediately.

Comment: Recall that in David's link, it was mentioned that a norm is induced by an inner product if and only if the parallelogram law holds. It does not hold for $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1.$ See if you can prove that in the two-dimensional case.

Answer (score 8):

Inner product spaces satisfy the [parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law).

If you can find a counterexample to the parallegram law in a space with the sup norm, then you've found a normed linear space that is not an inner product space.

Even more interestingly, inner product spaces are the ONLY normed vector spaces that satisfy the parallelogram law.

Answer (score 5):

Normed vector spaces with an inner product are, in fact, quite rare. For example
$L^p(X)$ is normed by
$$\Vert f\Vert_p := \left( \int_X |f|^p d\mu \right)^{\frac 1 p}$$
for all $1\leq p < \infty$ (and $\mathop {{\rm ess}\, \sup}_{x\in X} |f(x)|$ for $p=\infty$) but only has an inner product for $p=2$
$$\langle f,g \rangle_2 = \int_X f \bar{g} d\mu$$