# Prove that the norm of $E$ is generate by the inner product $\langle x,y \rangle =\frac{1}{4}\left(||x+y|^2-||x-y||^2\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $E$ a normed linear space such that:
$$\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2=2\|x\|^2+2\|y\|^2 $$
Prove that the norm of $E$ is generate by the inner product 
$$\langle x,y \rangle =\frac{1}{4}\left(\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2\right)$$ 
To prove this we have to prove three things: 
Bilinearity, symmetry, and positive definite.

**My approach:** Two of this parts are easy to prove. But the Bilinearity I think is difficult. 
Any hint is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law

Comment: Are you sure that right at the beginning is $\|x + y \|^2 - \|x - y \|^2$? I believe that it should be $\|x+y \|^2 + \|x - y\|^2$. The parallelogram law states that "the sum of the diagonals's squares equals the sum of the squares of the sides". A norm is generated by an inner product if and only if it satisfies the parallelogram law.

Comment: Is true!!! Thanks

Comment: See the changes a minus in the inner product definition.

Comment: This is more or less the same question as here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law