# Inner product induced norm vs $l_2$ norm

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

Some related problems:

1. [Relationship between inner product and norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957465/relationship-between-inner-product-and-norm)
2. [What norm Induced inner product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829952/what-norm-induced-inner-product)

My problem comes from one step of a certain proof:

> $\|Av\|^2=(Av)^T(Av)=v^TA^TAv=v^TIv = v^Tv =\|v\|^2 \Rightarrow \|Av\| = \|v\|$

Note: $A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

More general one:

> $\|Av\|^2=\langle Av,Av \rangle=\langle v,A^TAv \rangle=\langle v,Iv \rangle= \langle v,v\rangle=\|v\|^2 \Rightarrow \|Av\| = \|v\|$

They look similar.

It seems the above equality only holds on **$l_2$ norm**(the first case) and **inner product induced norm** (the second case).

So such equality cannot hold for general norm, right?

I just want to make my proof more strict.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, since you don't state any assumptions about, e.g., $A$. What the calculations show is that those operators which satisfy $A^TA = I$, where $(.)^T$ is the adjoint operation of the scalar product, are isometries of the norm induced by the scalar product.

Comment: What property on $A$ is given? Is it just an orthogonal matrix (linear operator) acting on a finite dimensional linear space?

Comment: @Thomas I fix that.

Comment: @b00nheT Yes $A$ is an  orthogonal matrix and finite dimensional linear space.

Comment: Then no. Just consider any other induced inner product induced by a positive definite symmetric matrix and its induced norm: i.e choose a PDS matrix $B$ and the inner product $(x,y):=x^\top B y$Then your orthogonality of $A$ (which is wrt the standard inner product) won't hold anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $A$ is an orthogonal linear map (i.e. $A^T A = I$), you are correct that $\|Av\| = \|v\|$ does not hold in general for norms other than the $2$-norm. For example, take $$A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
which you can check satisfies $A^T A = I$, and $$v = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and compute the $1$-norm of $Av = \begin{pmatrix}1\sqrt{2} \\ -1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$ and $v$: we see that $\|Av\|_1 = 2/\sqrt{2}$ whereas $\|v\|_1 = 1$.