# Can we have something like an orthonormal basis for a finite dimensional normed space?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, orthogonality

So I proved a certain theorem about finite dimensional inner-product spaces, but after completing the proof, I realized the only point where I used the idea of orthogonality was the construction of an orthonormal basis. Everywhere else, I just used the norm instead, which leads me to wonder if I could generalize the theorem to finite dimensional normed spaces as well. The proof would be the same everywhere except for the point where I use the orthonormal basis. I'd have to use a basis such that the norm of every member is $1$ and for two distinct vectors $x$ and $y$, 
$$||x+y||^2=||x||^2+||y||^2$$
Which is the analog of orthogonality in a normed space. So my question is, does such a basis exist for all finite dimensional normed spaces and if yes, how do we show the existence?
I'd be much obliged if you could give me some pointers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: I already know the Gram-Schmidt process. But that only works for inner product spaces. I want something for normed spaces.

Comment: There is no analogue in a general normed space, there is only linear independence in that setting. Indeed, if the norm doesn't satisfy the parallelogram law then you can't even pick a compatible inner product. You might be able to build a basis that has the property you mentioned, but it won't have any nice properties like those of orthogonal projection.

Comment: But I don't need a compatible inner product. All I need is a normal basis such that norms of the members add pythagoreously (is that even a term?) as shown above. Are you saying that requirement is equivalent to having a compatible inner product?

Comment: Yes. The inner product is constructed using the polarization identity.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get it now. Thanks. Could you convert your last couple of comments into an answer so I could close the question?

Comment: I think you could come up with a basis satisfying this for a given norm (e.g in the sup norm, $x = (1,0), y = (\sqrt 2 - 1,1)$ works, I'm pretty sure), but I don't know an outline of a constructive procedure (like gram-schmidt) for a general norm. Nor, as Ian suggests, will this basis have nice properties. For instance, another choice for $y$ above is $y = (\sqrt 3 - 1, \sqrt{2})$, but this $y$ isn't "parallel" (a multiple of) my first choice for $y$.

Comment: I'm not so much interested in the construction of the basis as much as the truth of existence for a wide class of normed spaces.

Comment: I guess it's also worth noting that my second example doesn't have unit norm.

Answer (score 6):

As a very beginning, this is true for all  real normed spaces of dimension 2.  (For dimension 0 and 1 it is trivial.)

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be any norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and choose any $x$ with $\|x\|=1$.  Let $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ be any continuous path connecting $x$ to $-x$ that avoids 0.   Set $f(t) = \left\| x + \frac{\gamma(t)}{\|\gamma(t)\|}\right\|^2$, so that $f(0)=\|x+x\|^2 = 4$ and $f(1) = \|x-x\|^2=0$.  Now $f$ is continuous, so by the intermediate value theorem there exists $t_0$ such that $f(t_0) = 2$.  Set $y = \frac{\gamma(t_0)}{\|\gamma(t_0)\|}$.  Then $\|y\|^2 = 1$ so $\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2$ as desired.  Moreover, clearly $y$ is neither $x$ nor $-x$ so $\{x,y\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Note that if you want to use this to prove something, you should be *extremely careful* that the only property of "orthonormal basis" you use is that $\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 = 2$.  Many other properties of orthonormal bases won't hold in general.  For example, the "Pythagorean theorem" $\|ax+by\|^2 = a^2 + b^2$ need not hold.  (Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the sup norm, $x = (1,0)$, $y=(\sqrt{2}-1, 1)$, $a=2$, $b=1$.  Then $\|ax+by\|^2 = \|(1+\sqrt{2}, 1)\|^2 = (1+\sqrt{2})^2 \ne 2^2 + 1^2$.)

Comment: Interesting proof!

Answer (score 0):

This addresses a slightly different question, but I think it is the case that the only real normed spaces in which the parallelogram law $\|x+y\|^{2} + \|x-y\|^{2} = 2(\|x\|^{2} + \|y\|^{2})$ holds are inner product spaces.

Comment: Yes, this is true; see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law

Comment: @NateEldredge : Thanks, I knew it was true, I was just being a bit understated, as I couldn't locate a proper reference. It's also true for complex normed spaces.