# Generalization of inner product spaces (analogue to uniform spaces/locally convex spaces)

Tags: general-topology, inner-products, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, uniform-spaces

In the following I am going to devise a chart of topological spaces that contains *inner product spaces*, *normed vector spaces*, *metric spaces* and other related spaces. In the end there will be a gap in the chart and, essentially, my question is how to fill this gap.

---

**Step 1: Spaces with positive definite structures**
A topological space can be generated, e. g., by some structure like **inner products**, **norms** and **metrics**. Inner products, norms and metrics have one property in common: They are positive definite.

- $\langle x,x\rangle \geq 0$ and $(\langle x,x\rangle =0 \implies x=0)$
- $||x|| \geq 0$ and $(||x||=0 \implies x=0)$
- $d(x,y) \geq 0$ and $(d(x,y)=0 \implies x=y)$

It is well known that each *inner product* induces a *norm* and each *norm* induces a *metric*.

---

**Step 2: Spaces with positive semi-definite structures**
If we relax the positive definite properties a bit, we are left with positive semi-definite structures:

- Instead of **inner products** we then have **symmetric positive semi-definite bilinear forms** (or **hermitian positive semi-definite sesquilinear forms**). I'll call them **semi-inner products** below; please note that this name isn't used consistently in literature/internet.
- Instead of **norms** we then have **semi-norms**.
- Instead of **metrics** we then have **pseudometrics**.

And again, one can show that each semi-inner product induces a semi-norm and each semi-norm induces a pseudometric.

---

**Step 3: Spaces with families of positive semi-definite structures**

- The *generalization of a metric space* is called a **uniform space**. Uniform structures are connected to pseudometrics: one way to define uniform spaces is via a **family of pseudometrics**.
  <sup>See for example *Bourbaki, General Topology II, Chapter IX, §1, section 2, Definition of a uniformity by means of a family of pseudometrics*.</sup>
- The *generalization of a normed vector space* is called a **locally convex space**. Locally convex spaces can be defined by a **family of semi-norms** on a vector space.
  <sup>See for example [the Wikipedia article on locally convex spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space#Seminorms).</sup>

Locally convex spaces can be interpreted as a subclass of uniform spaces.

---

**Summary:**
Essentially, what we get is the following chart of structures and spaces, where every arrow can be read as "is a/can be interpreted as a":

```
POS. DEF. STRUCTURE   |   POS. SEMI-DEF. STRUCTURE   |  FAM. OF POS. SEMI-DEF. STRUCTURES
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Inner product space  -->  Semi-inner product space  -->    ???
        |                        |                          |
        V                        V                          V
Normed vector space  -->  Semi-normed vector space  -->  Locally convex space
        |                        |                          |
        V                        V                          V
Metric space         -->  Pseudometric space        -->  Uniform space
```

---

**My questions:**
How can the gap ("???") in the chart above be filled? Is there a *generalization of an inner product space* that is constructed using a **family of semi-inner products** similarly to how uniform spaces and locally convex spaces can be constructed by families of pseudometrics and semi-norms? Do these generalized inner product spaces have a special name I haven't found out yet and have they ever been systematically studied?

Comment: I think the question is advanced enough that it can be addressed on mathoverflow. (After a quick Google-session I don't have an answer to your question.)

Comment: I am uncertain about migration to MO. I added the *topological-vector-spaces* tag. For it seemes to me that to you *a space* is always a vector space. This is not the case, for example, in general topology. I cannot help you with the actual question, for I'm not a functional analyst. May be there simply is no interesting subclass of topological vector spaces to fill in that spot?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: No, I don't necessarily mean "vector space" by "space". Metric spaces, pseudometric spaces and uniform spaces clearly need not be vector spaces.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I don't disagree with your adding a tag, though, because my ???-space *is* a (subclass of) locally convex space and thus a topological vector space.

Answer (score 1):

One can show that each (semi-)norm that satisfies the [parallelogram identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law)

$$ 2\lVert x\rVert^2 + 2\lVert y\rVert^2 = \lVert x + y\rVert^2 + \lVert x - y\rVert^2 $$

is generated by a (semi-)inner product. This has been examined, e. g., in [this question here on Math Stack Exchange.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law) We can conclude:

- **Inner product spaces** are precisely those **normed vector spaces** whose norms satisfy the parallelogram identity.
- **Semi-inner product spaces** are precisely those **semi-normed vector spaces** whose semi-norms satisfy the parallelogram identity.
- **???-spaces** are precisely those **locally convex spaces** of whose family of semi-norms each one satisfies the parallelogram identity.

[According to a paper by Hicks and Huffman](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022247X78900045/1-s2.0-0022247X78900045-main.pdf?_tid=732ae386-e86a-11e4-b79c-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1429650642_2b24fb728eff982663f23685b6f06fec), Precupanu has named  these spaces ***H-locally convex spaces***. If such a space is complete, it is called a ***Generalized Hilbert space***. Some properties:

- In the above paper, Hicks and Huffman prove some fixed point theorems - so, H-locally convex spaces seem to have some interesting properties that are/have been worth studying.
- [Naimpally, Singh and Whitfield](https://books.google.de/books?id=k-R34u9RNcUC&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=precupanu+hilbert+parallelogram+identity&source=bl&ots=0REryRvf1Q&sig=5Qid3voOxPB5FrmOYcVwyX5kWeQ&hl=de&sa=X&ei=mBs0Ve33KonfapCkgZAK&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=precupanu%20hilbert%20parallelogram%20identity&f=false) mention that [nuclear spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_space) are a subset of generalized Hilbert spaces.

---

To give a summary, I reproduce the chart of spaces with H-locally convex spaces filled in:

```
POS. DEF. STRUCTURE   |   POS. SEMI-DEF. STRUCTURE   |  FAM. OF POS. SEMI-DEF. STRUCTURES
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Inner product space  -->  Semi-inner product space  -->  H-locally convex spaces
        |                        |                          |
        V                        V                          V
Normed vector space  -->  Semi-normed vector space  -->  Locally convex space
        |                        |                          |
        V                        V                          V
Metric space         -->  Pseudometric space        -->  Uniform space
```

---