# Sesquilinear Forms: Parallelogram

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, sesquilinear-forms

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a quadratic form:
$$q:\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{C}:\quad q[\lambda\varphi]=|\lambda|^2q[\varphi]$$

Suppose one has:
$$q[\varphi+\psi]+q[\varphi-\psi]=2q[\varphi]+2q[\psi]$$

Define a sesquilinear form:
$$s:\mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{C}:\quad s(\varphi,\psi):=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}i^\alpha q[\varphi+i^\alpha\psi]$$

> Then it is sesquilinear:
>   $$s(\varphi+\varphi',\psi)=s(\varphi,\psi)+s(\varphi',\psi)\quad s(\kappa\varphi,\psi)=\kappa s(\varphi,\psi)$$
>   $$s(\varphi,\psi+\psi')=s(\varphi,\psi)+s(\varphi,\psi')\quad s(\varphi,\lambda \psi)=\lambda s(\varphi,\psi)$$

How can I check this?

Comment: Implicit in what you write is that $s_{q}$ will be sesquilinear. That may not be true. You'll get $s_{q}(\alpha x,y) = \alpha s_{q}(x,y)$ for $\alpha$ with rational real and imaginary parts, but not necessarily for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Claim:** There exists a function $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, but which is not linear.

**Proof of claim:** To prove the existence of $f$, define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
                   x \sim y  \mbox{ iff } y-x \in\mathbb{Q}.
$$
This defines equivalence classes $[x] = \{ y \in \mathbb{R} : y \sim x \}$.
As with all equivalence relations, either $[x]\cap[y] = \emptyset$ or $[x]=[y]$. The collection of equivalence classes becomes a vector space over the field of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ under the operations
$$
             [x]+[y]=[x+y],\;\;\; \alpha[x]=[\alpha x],\;\;\;\alpha\in\mathbb{Q},\;x,y\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
These linear operations are well-defined because $x\sim x'$, $y\sim y'$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$ give
$$
                   x+y \sim x'+y',\;\;\; \alpha x \sim \alpha x'.
$$
So the space $X$ consisting of all equivalence classes $[x]$ is a linear space over the field of rational numbers. Hence, $X$ has a Hamel basis $\{ [x_{\alpha}]\}_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$. Now, for any choice function $\{s_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in S}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ from $\Lambda$ to $\mathbb{R}$, there is a unique function $F : X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is linear over $\mathbb{Q}$ and satisfies:
$$
                       F([x_{\alpha}]) = s_{\alpha}.
$$
The function $f(x) = F([x])$ is additive and is linear over $\mathbb{Q}$, but you can choose $\{ s_{\alpha} \}$ so that $f$ is not linear. $\;\;\Box$

**Quadratic Form from an Additive Function:** For any additive function $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, the following defines a quadratic form
$$
                q(x) = (f(x))^{2}.
$$
This is easily checked:
\begin{align}
         q(x+y)+q(x-y) & = (f(x)+f(y))^{2}+(f(x)-f(y))^{2}\\
                       & = 2f(x)^{2}+2f(y)^{2} = 2q(x)+2q(y).
\end{align}
An additive function on $\mathbb{R}$ is always linear over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$. But without some kind of measurability or continuity, the function $f$ may not be linear over $\mathbb{R}$, which is equivalent to continuity over $\mathbb{R}$.

> **Theorem:** An additive function $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is linear over $\mathbb{R}$ iff it is Lebesgue measurable. Equivalently, $f$ is continuous.

**What makes a norm different?:** There is a classic theorem which states that a norm is generated by an inner product iff the norm satisfies the parallelogram law. The proof generally starts by showing that, if $\|\cdot\|$ satisfies the Parallelogram Law, the function
$$
        \rho(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^{n}\|x+i^{n}y\|^{2}
$$
is additive in both coordinates $x$, $y$. Then it follows that $\rho(q x,y)=\rho(x,qy) = q\rho(x,y)$ for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. If you're dealing with a complex space, then $\rho(ix,y)=i\rho(x,y)$ and $\rho(x,iy)=-i\rho(x,y)$ follow from $\|ix\|=\|x\|$. What makes the norm different is that $\rho(x,x) \ge 0$; hence, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds:
$$
                |\rho(x,y)|^{2} \le \rho(x,x)\rho(y,y) = \|x\|^{2}\|y\|^{2}
$$
From this you get continuity of $\rho(x,y)$ with respect to the norm. So, for real $r$ and rational $\{ q_{n} \}$ converging to $r$,
$$
\begin{align}
      |\rho(rx,y)-q_{n}\rho(x,y)|
            & \le \|rx-q_{n}x\|\|y\| \\
            & =|r-q_{n}|\|x\|\|y\|\rightarrow 0.
\end{align}
$$
And that's enough to guarantee that $\rho(rx,y)=r\rho(x,ry)$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

The result below is useful for proving that a quadratic form arises from a sesquilinear form.

> **Theorem: [Bounded Quadratic Form Representation]** Let $Q$ be a quadratic form on a complex linear space $X$. If there exists a seminorm $|\cdot|$ on $X$ such that $|Q(x)| \le |x|^{2}$, then $Q(x)= S(x,x)$ for a unique sesquilinear form $S(\cdot,\cdot)$ on $X\times X$.

Comment: Ok so for additive functions this may fail: $q[x]=f(x)^2$ But what for sesquilinear forms: $q[x]:=s(x,x)$

Comment: @Freeze_S : What would be the point? If you know that a quadratic form comes from a sesquilinear form, then obviously you can recover the sesquilinear form the quadratic form. The key point is that not all quadratic forms come from sesquilinear forms. That's a common misconception, and it's intimately tied to the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for then: Is there a quadratic form satisfying the parallelogram identity but still does not come from a sesquilinear form? *(Counterexample)*

Comment: @Freeze_S : I gave you one on $\mathbb{R}^{1}$. That's a building block you can use to trivially extend to any dimension. Any discontinuous additive function leads to a quadratic form satisfying the parallelogram law, and the associated form gives you back the additive function, which is not linear. In this case, the form is $f(x)f(y)$--additive in both coordinates, but not linear. Think about it for a bit.

Comment: Can I deduce from $q[x]=f(x)^2$ that $s(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$?

Comment: Moreover how to extend this to the complex case - especially since this fails in the real case already for non-symmetric bilinear forms?

Comment: @Freeze_S : It fails for symmetric forms. It fails for positive forms. It fails for positive definite forms. It fails period. I cannot emphasize this enough because you seem to be missing that point. You need continuity of $\alpha\mapsto q(x+\alpha y)$ at $\alpha=0$ for all $x,y$ in order for the quadratic form to be generated by a sesquilinear form. If $q$ is a real positive form with $q(\alpha x)=|\alpha|^{2}q(x)$, you get that continuity. Or if $|q(x)|$ is dominated by such a form, you get the needed continuity. If the continuity fails for some $x$, $y$, the result is FALSE.

Comment: Continuity is sufficient for existence of a sesquilinear form but not necessary; take $s(x,y):=\langle Ax,By\rangle$ and $q[x]:=s(x,x)$ for unbounded operators $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Freeze_S : We are talking about scalar continuity here at $\alpha=0$: $\alpha \mapsto q(x+\alpha y)$. Necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @Freeze_S : I see I missed one of your questions. Yes, if $q(x)=f(x)^{2}$ for the example I gave you, then the associated form $b(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(q(x+y)-q(x-y))=\frac{1}{4}((f(x)+f(y))^{2}-(f(x)-f(y))^{2})=f(x)f(y)$ because $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y$.

Answer (score 1):

*As positive result...*

**Additivity**

Introduce the forms:
$$s_\Re(\varphi,\psi):=\frac{1}{4}\{q[\varphi+\psi]-q[\varphi-\psi]\}$$
$$s_\Im(\varphi,\psi):=\frac{1}{4}\{q[\varphi+i\psi]-q[\varphi-i\psi]\}$$

They reconstruct it:
$$s(\varphi,\psi)=s_\Re(\varphi,\psi)+is_\Im(\varphi,\psi)$$

Note the relations:
$$s_\Re(\psi,\varphi)=s_\Re(\varphi,\psi)\quad s_\Im(\varphi,\psi)=s_\Re(\varphi,i\psi)$$

By parallelogram law:*

$$s_\Re(\varphi+\varphi'+\psi)=s_\Re(\varphi,\psi)+s_\Re(\varphi',\psi)$$

That gives additivity.

**See the check: [Sesquilinearity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/43848/79762)*

**Homogenity**

> Suppose Cauchy-Schwarz holds:
>   $$|s(\varphi,\psi)|^2\leq q[\varphi]q[\psi]$$

By construction one has:
$$s(i\varphi,\psi)=is(\varphi,\psi)\quad s(\varphi,i\psi)=-is(\varphi,\psi)$$

From additivity it follows:
$$qs\left(\tfrac{p}{q}\varphi,\psi\right)=s\left(q\tfrac{p}{q}\varphi,\psi\right)=ps\left(\tfrac{q}{q}\varphi,\psi\right)$$
$$qs\left(\varphi,\tfrac{p}{q}\psi\right)=s\left(\varphi,q\tfrac{p}{q}\psi\right)=ps\left(\varphi,\tfrac{q}{q}\psi\right)$$

By continuity one obtains:
$$0\leq|rs(\varphi,\psi)-s(r\varphi,\psi)|\leq2|r-r_n|\sqrt{q[\varphi]q[\psi]}\to0$$
$$0\leq|rs(\varphi,\psi)-s(\varphi,r\psi)|\leq2|r-r_n|\sqrt{q[\varphi]q[\psi]}\to0$$

That gives homogenity.

**Caution**

For real forms it is:
$$q\subseteq\mathbb{R}:\quad\Re s(\varphi,\psi)=s_\Re(\varphi,\psi)\quad\Im s(\varphi,\psi)=s_\Im(\varphi,\psi)$$

Else, notation is symbolic!