# Sesquilinear Forms: Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, sesquilinear-forms

*This thread is related: [Parallelogram](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1249970/79762)*

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a quadratic form:
$$q:\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{C}:\quad q[\lambda\varphi]=|\lambda|^2q[\varphi]$$

Suppose it satisfies:
$$q[\varphi+\psi]+q[\varphi-\psi]=2q[\varphi]+2q[\psi]$$

Define a sesquilinear form:
$$s:\mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{C}:\quad s(\varphi,\psi):=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}i^\alpha q[\varphi+i^\alpha\psi]$$

> Then for positive forms:
>   $$q\geq0:\quad|s(\varphi,\psi)|\leq q[\varphi]q[\psi]$$

How can I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need only assume $Q$ is real and non-negative on a complex space with
$$
         Q(x+y)+Q(x-y)=2Q(x)+2Q(y),\\
              Q(ix)=Q(x).
$$
Then it is true that $B(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^{n}Q(x+i^{n}y)$ satisfies
$$
           |B(x,y)| \le Q(x)^{1/2}Q(y)^{1/2}.
$$
Therefore $|x|_{Q}=Q(x)^{1/2}$ satisfies the triangle inequality. Then, if $Q(\lambda x)=|\lambda|^{2}Q(x)$ holds for all scalars $\lambda$, it is also true that $B$ is sesquilinear.

**Outline**

1. $B(x+x',y)=B(x,y)+B(x',y)$. So $B(\alpha x,y)=\alpha B(x,y)$ for all complex scalars with rational real and imaginary parts.
2. $4|B(x,y)|=\lim_{n}4B(\alpha_n x,y)= \lim_{n}Q(\alpha_n x + y)-Q(\alpha_n x-y) \le 2Q(x)+2Q(y)$ if $Q(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$.
3. Use rational positive real scalars to obtain $|B(rx,sy)| \le 1$ and $|B(x,y)| \le Q(x)^{1/2}Q(y)^{1/2}$.
4. Continuity: $|\lambda B(x,y)-B(\lambda x,y)|=\lim_{n}|B((\lambda_n-\lambda)x,y)|\le\lim_{n}|\lambda_{n}-\lambda|Q(x)^{1/2}Q(y)^{1/2}=0$ if $Q(\alpha x)=|\alpha|^{2}Q(x)$. So $\lambda B(x,y)=B(\lambda x,y)$ for general $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. That makes $B$ fully sesquilinear.

Comment: Yes and how can I check Cqauchy-Schwarz: $|B(x,y)|\leq Q(x)^{1/2}Q(y)^{1/2}$

Comment: @Freeze_S I've given you the outline, and will let you fill in the pieces.

Comment: Number '3' is the normalization trick??

Comment: Number '2' restricts to hermitian forms??

Comment: Decomposing arbitrary form into: $s=s_\Re^++s_\Re^-+is_\Im^++is_\Im^-$

Comment: Ok I'm way to tired.. Let me just believe it for now. :)

Comment: @Freeze_S : #1 is general for $B$ coming from a general $Q$. The additivity gives linearity over rational scalars because $B(nx,y)=nB(x,y)$ and $mB(\frac{1}{m}x,y)=B(x,y)$ gives $B(\frac{1}{m}x,y)=\frac{1}{m}B(x,y)$ for positive integers $m$, $n$. <br><br> #2 is specific to $Q$ real and non-negative.<br><br>#3 uses (1) and limits of rationals along with (2) to get the tight Cauchy-Schwarz bound.<br><br>#4 uses (3) and $Q(\lambda x)=|\lambda|^{2}Q(x)$ to derive continuity. Or instead assume $Q(x) \le C|x|$ for some seminorm $|\cdot|$, which you can see directly. So $Q \ge 0$ bounded is enough.

Comment: Ya I guessed already that taking first positive quadratic forms is necessary to obtain the 'tight' Cauchy-Schwarz. Otherwise one probably obtains a factor 2 or 4 to much that cannot be killed afterwards. Right?

Comment: @Freeze_S : Yes, that's right. But you get Cauchy-Schwarz only having linearity over the rational complex scalars IF $Q \ge 0$. That, however, is not enough to give full linearity over $\mathbb{Q}$. But, $Q(\lambda x)=|\lambda|^{2}Q(x)$ then turns $|x|=Q(x)$ into a full-blow seminorm. And you really only need $Q(x) \le |x|$ for some seminorm $|\cdot|$ with $Q \ge 0$ to also force $Q$ to be a seminorm. Either condition forces continuity over the scalar field and, sesquiinearity for $B$. This stuff is tricky and wrapped up with the axiom of choice.

Comment: Mhh yes. Like measurability and continuity as you mentioned earlier..

Comment: By the way isn't there the hypothesis in ZF: $AC\iff WE\iff Zorn\iff Hamel\iff Baire\stackrel{???}{\iff} UBP\iff OMT\iff CGT\iff Zabreiko$

Comment: @Freeze_S : I'm not sure of all of those. What is Zabreiko?

Comment: See on wiki: [Baire vs. AC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem#Relation_to_the_axiom_of_choice) See on MSE: [Zabreiko](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/138005/79762)

Comment: @Freeze_S : In this case, you end up with additive functions on $\mathbb{R}$, which is to say that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. And you want to know if $f$ is linear. $f$ is linear iff it is continuous. $f$ is linear over every set $x\mathbb{Q}=\{ x q : q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ because $f(xq)=qf(x)$. You can partition $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ into sets by the equivalent relation $x \sim y$ iff $x/y \in \mathbb{Q}$. This is very closely related to the classical construction of a non-measurable set. Consequently, if $f$ is meausrable, then it is continuous.