# Does the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ induce any other norms other than the 2 norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

In the lecture my professor wrote that the standard inner product on $R^n$ is given by

$\langle x, y \rangle = x^Ty = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$

which induces a norm $\sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle} = \|x\|_2$

My question is do inner products induce other types of norms...or rather are norms such as the 1-norm or the $\infty$-norm induces by some inner product?

Comment: I think that the code $\langle x,y\rangle$ `\langle x,y\rangle` is used more often.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a really interesting question, and here is a partial answer.  The $1$ and $\infty$ norms do not come from inner products.  For a norm to have an associated inner product actually gives you a lot of structure.  For example (if the scalars are real for convenience),
$$\left\| x - y \right\|^2 = \langle x - y, x -y \rangle = \langle x, x \rangle - 2 \langle x, y \rangle + \langle y, y \rangle = \left\|x \right\|^2 - 2 \langle x, y \rangle + \left\| y \right\|^2$$
In fact it turns out that there is an identity called the parallelogram law
$$2 \left\|x\right\|^2 + 2\left\|y\right\|^2 = \left\|x + y \right\| + \left\| x - y\right\|$$ 
A norm obeys this identity iff it has an associated inner product.  You can verify that the $1$ and $\infty$ norms do not obey this identity (by finding examples), and therefore cannot have an inner product.  In fact the $p$-norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ only obey this identity when $p=2$.

Thanks to the comments for some additions.  For a proof of the "iff" claim, see [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law).  If you have a norm which obeys the parallelogram law, you can actually express the inner product directly in terms of the norm by (again real case for convenience)
$$\langle x, y \rangle = \frac{1}{4} \left( \left\| x + y \right\|^2 - \left\| x - y \right\|^2 \right)$$
See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) for more information.

Comment: It bears mentioning that an inner product can be "recovered" from a norm obeying the parallelogram law via the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)

Comment: See this question plus answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law. There it is shown that the validity of the parallelogram law suffices to induce an inner product. The converse is even easier, though.

Comment: In fact, take $||x+y||^2$ in the first formula and add them up to receive the parallelogram law.

Answer (score 4):

Every inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as $\langle x, y \rangle = x^t A y$, where $A$ is a (symmetric) positive definite matrix. These matrices can be orthogonally diagonalized, i.e. there is an orthogonal matrix $M$ so that $A = M^t \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n) M$. This means in particular $\langle x, y \rangle = (Mx)^t \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n) (Mx)$.

Now note that the open balls with respect to the inner product $\langle x, y \rangle = x^t \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n) y$ are ellipsoids and the map $x \mapsto Mx$ is essentially the composition of reflections and rotations [of course this can only be visualized for $n \le 3$]. So the open balls of an arbitrary inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are rotated and reflected ellipsoids.

Comment: Could you go into detail how to note that the open balls are ellipsoids? This is the crucial point, isn't it?

Comment: @tomglabst This pretty much follows directly from the definition of an ellipsoid. Note that the induced norm satisfies $\| x \|^2 = \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \lambda_k x_k^2$.