# Show that norm is induced by a scalar product

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider $I = [-1,1]$. Let $C(I)$ be the normed space, equipped with norm
\begin{align}
||f||_{2} = \left( \int_{-1}^{1} |f(t)|^2 \, dt \right) ^{1/2}
\end{align}

Show, that norm is induced by a scalar product. Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: You want that $\left<f,f\right> = \Vert f \Vert^2$. Remember that $\vert f \vert^2 = ff^*$ with $f^*$ being the complex conjugate of $f$.

Comment: You might want to look up "polarization identity." And then you might want to think about how lucky you are that your field doesn't have characteristic 2.

Comment: Use polarization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any norm in a Hilbert space is induced by a scalar product, to do this you can use the polarization identity:

$$\langle f,g\rangle=\frac{1}{4}\left(||f+g||^2-||f-g||^2\right),$$
where $||f||$ is the norm that you described before.

Answer (score 0):

As many has pointed out, what you need is the [Polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity). Basically, it tells you when the converse of "every inner product induces a norm" is true. The special case where the field of the vector space is real is spelled out in Diego's post. For complex case the formula is
$$
\langle f,g \rangle=\frac 14 \sum_{n=0}^3 i^n||f+i^ng||^2
$$
For more discussion and proofs, consider reading this link [Norms Induced by Inner Products and the Parallelogram Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law?lq=1).