# Proving that given this property then the norm is induced by a inner product

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a normed space such that, for $x,y\in X$

$$||x + y||^2 +||x - y||^2 = 2||x||^2 + 2||y||^2$$.

Then I want to check that $||\cdot||$ is induced by an inner product, so what I was trying to do is to check that the norm looks like $\sqrt{(x,x)}$ but I can't fugure out how to do this only knowing the above equation, then I have tried to use the polarization equalities to get the result, the thing is that I want to check that the norm is induced by a inner product and not the converse.

Then, Can someone help me to prove this result please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that you're on the right track: The polarization identity tells you what the inner product ought to be, so one need only show that for $||\cdot||$, the operator $X \times X \to \Bbb R$ defined by the usual polarization identity *is* an inner product, and that the norm it induces is $||\cdot||$ itself.

Comment: Can you clarify the last part of your comment please? :)

Comment: the thing is How do you proof the last part ?

Comment: If we denote the product defined by the polarization formula by $\langle\,\cdot\, ,\,\cdot\,\rangle$, then the second step is simply checking that $\langle x, x\rangle = ||x||^2$

Comment: Right jajajaja I apologize for the question jajajaja

Comment: @Travis _But_ verifying that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ actually _is_ an inner product is not at all trivial.

Comment: So Is the second answer of this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law complete? :)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, I certainly did not intend to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @user162343 In what sense is this question not a duplicate of the linked one?

Comment: So then what do you think about my above comment ? :)

Comment: @Travis Ok. Sounded to me like you were saying the problem was trivial, which it's really not.

Comment: Is because I have seen that question whaen I post mine in the right hand side od my computer screen :) sorry, but there are things of continous functions that are not expalined right?