# How did Von Neumann think of the formula for scalar product?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

My question is on the idea behind Von Neumann's formula for the scalar product induced from a norm that satisfies the parallelogram law.
$\langle x,y\rangle=\frac 14(\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2)$.
Was it by trial and error or is there some intuitive way that one can guess this formula?

I can prove that this is indeed a scalar product, it is the idea behind it that baffles me.

Comment: That is classical elementary plane geometry. I suggest you read the Wikipedia page on the Parallelogram Law.

Comment: This is a well known identity for the 2-norm -- for example, this identity is used to prove that a linear transformation that preserves the 2-norm also preserves inner products. You can prove the identity easily (for the 2-norm)  by expanding the right hand side.

Comment: @littleO thanks I get it now

Comment: I will add link to the post where the proofs about this can be found: [Norms Induced by Inner Products and the Parallelogram Law](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law). (It is not what you ask about, but if somebody stumbles upon your post, this link might be useful for them.)