# Normed space.. inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis

Every inner product space is normed space but the converse is not true,  what is the condition we must have to make the converse true?

Comment: It must satisfy the parallelogram law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm must satisfy the parallelogram identity, i.e., you must have $||x+y|| ^2 + || x-y||^2 = 2 ( ||x||^2 + ||y||^2)$.

Look at the post here [Norms Induced by Inner Products and the Parallelogram Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law) for a proof. (The complex case is done similarly)

Answer (score 2):

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space. Then, $\|\cdot\|$ arises from an inner product if, and only if, it satisfies the parallelogram law:

$$\|x+y\|^2 + \|x - y\|^2 = 2(\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2)$$

for all $x,y \in X$.