# When is a norm induced by an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, geometry, normed-spaces, inner-products

Do inner products come from a norm, 
or norms come from an inner product?

How do I prove that this is true?

Just want to know what comes from what, the chicken or the egg came first kind of thing.

Comment: Every inner product gives rise to a norm, but not every norm comes from an inner product. (For example, $\|\cdot\|_p$ in $\mathbb R^n$ corresponds to an inner product only if $n\le 1$ or $p=2$).

Answer (score 9):

An inner product $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$ gives the norm $||x|| = \langle x ,x \rangle^{1/2}$. The axioms for a norm here are fairly easy to verify. In general, an inner product does not come from a norm. However, a norm $||\cdot||$is induced by an inner product if and only if it satisfies the parallelogram law: $$||x+y||^2 + ||x-y||^2 = 2(||x||^2+||y||^2)$$ If you want to see how to prove this, I think this answer: ([Norms Induced by Inner Products and the Parallelogram Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law)) is very helpful. In response to "what came first", the inner product is a natural generalization of the standard dot product from Euclidean geometry. Of course the dot product also comes with an induced norm so I guess the two concepts appeared simultaneously.