# Norm from a scalar product only for $p = 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

How to prove that the following norm, defined on $C([0,1],\mathbb{C})$ :

$||f||_p = (\int_0^1 |f(t)|^p dt)^{1/p}$ (for $p \in [1,+\infty[$) is "from" a scalar product only if $p=2$ ?

I don't know how to show it at all, I need food for thought... Thank you in advance !

Comment: Two questions, as food for thought: (1) can you define "scalar product"? (2) can you write down precisely what you mean by "from"? (In other words, can you write down a formula for what the scalar product $\langle f,g\rangle$ will be if it exists?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your name is French, I assume with scalar product (produit scalaire) that you're talking about the inner product.

You could use that the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces) holds if and only if the norm is induced by an inner product. So you only need to check that $$2\|f\|_p^2+2\|g\|_p^2=\|f+g\|_p^2+\|f-g\|_p^2 $$
holds for all $f,g\in C([0,1],\mathbb{C})$ only for $p=2$.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) contains more details about the proof of the parallelogram law.

Comment: I really thank you ! Indeed, "scalar product" is "inner product" and "from" means "induced by" in my post. I'll see the topic you link :)