# Hardy inner product for the right half plane

Tags: hilbert-spaces, hardy-spaces

> The Hardy space $H^\infty(\mathbb{C_+})$ is defined to be the space of all functions $f$ >analytic and bounded on the complex right half plane $\mathbb{C_+}$ with the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_H$
>
> $\lVert f \rVert_H^\infty=\sup_{z\in\mathbb{C_+}}|f(z)|$
>
> Give an example of an inner product for  $H^\infty(\mathbb{C_+})$

I've managed to prove that  $\lVert \cdot \rVert_H$ is indeed a norm, but couldn't find the inner product induced by it.

Edit:
As the comments pointed out, there is no inner product induced by the norm above. But I also couldn't find any **other** inner product for the Hardy subspace.

Comment: What makes you think that this norm is given by an inner product?

Comment: You are right. in fact, I'm starting to believe that the norm above **does not** induced by any inner product.

Comment: See [norm induced by inner product if and only if satisfies the parallelogram law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law).

Comment: You are right, it is not induced by an inner product, can you suggest an inner product for the hardy space for the right half plane?