# If $H^*$ is isomorphic with $H$ is H always a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $H$ is a Hilbert space then $H^*$ is isomorphic with $H$. I am asking if we have a vector space H equipped with inner product (*,*) and $H^*$ is isomorphic with $H$ is it true to say that $H$ is Hilbert?
Edit:I am also interested for cases that the norm of H is not the ordinary norm given from inner product

Comment: Yes, because the dual space is complete

Comment: yes the norm is the ordinary given from inner product

Comment: One can ask if a Banach space $X$ isometrically isomorphic to its dual  is a Hilbert space.

Comment: The vector space with inner product need not be $H$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor If H is a general normed linear space then N* is complete(even if the case that H is not complete;).If thats right i am also thinking of cases that H is a Banach space but is not Hilbert(because H does not come from inner product).For example if you consider l2 with his ordinary norm its a Hilber space but if we consider an equivalent norm with the || ||2 such as ||x||=||x||2+||x||00(notice that ||x||2<=||x||<=2||x||2 so l2 is Banach with the || || norm)

Comment: but its not Hilbert because rectangle rule does not hold(||e1+e2||^2+||e1-e2||^2=2(sqrt(2)+1)^2 that is not equal to 2||e1||^2+2||e2||^2=16).

Comment: I could understand your question (although maybe wrongly?) but your comments are getting to be too much. Please see this [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to type mathematics on this site

Comment: In particular your first comment said that the norm was given by the inner product which [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law) that it satisfies parallelogram law. What is the relationship of $H$ to $N$?  the equivalent norm you gave for $\ell^2$ is not induced by any inner product

Comment: Ok i understand the general case if i give $H$ the general norm given from inner product just because $H^*$ is always complete so $H$ is complete.In my comment I meant $H^*$ (not $N^*$).What i wanted to say is that $\ell^2*$ is isomorphic with $\ell^2$.So i consider $H^*$=$\ell^2$ with the ordinary norm and $H$=$\ell^2$ with the || || norm then $H^*$ is a Hilbert space(since $\ell^2$ is) but $H$ is not a Hilbert space since rectangle rule does not hold(despite the fact that H is complete).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is No.
A non Hilbert space can be isometric (not just isomorphic) with his Dual.
For example $X:=(\ell^2,\lVert $.$\rVert_{\ell^2} +\lVert $.$\rVert_{\infty})$, $X\cong X^*$ ,and obviously is not a hilbert space.

Comment: I think that Since $X*$ is always dual space X will be also dual space(because of isometry).The only problem is that inner product is not transfered through isometry.If we have the norm given from inner product its correct otherwise its not!