# If $d$ is a metric of the metric space that satisfies the Law of the Parallelogram, is the metric induced by an internal product?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

If $d$ is a metric of the metric space that satisfies the [Law of the Parallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law), is the metric induced by an internal product?

I thought about using [the polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) to write the internal product in terms of the metric and prove that it is in fact an internal product. But I cannot conclude using the Law of the parallelogram

Comment: Can you show your attempts? Incidentally, this is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21792/443030

Comment: I guess you mean a *normed space*.