# How can one prove the dot product is distributive with respect to addition when it is defined solely in terms of the length of vectors?

Tags: vectors

If the dot product is defined as below, how can it be proven that it is distributive over addition?

$$ \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\Vert \mathbf{u} \Vert^2 + \Vert \mathbf{v} \Vert^2 - \Vert \mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v} \Vert^2\bigg) $$

I tried using the polarization identity and using the fact that

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
 - \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v_1} + \mathbf{v_2} = \bigg(\mathbf{v_1} - \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{u}\bigg) + \bigg(\mathbf{v_2} - \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{u}\bigg) \\
\quad \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v_1} + \mathbf{v_2} = \bigg(\mathbf{v_1} + \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{u}\bigg) + \bigg(\mathbf{v_2} + \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{u}\bigg)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

But still couldn't figure out how to prove it.

Comment: Hi, welcome.  On this site it's expected that you show your work so and explain where you are confused, instead of pasting the problem and requesting a solution.  A hint: do some research on the “polarization identity” for normed linear spaces

Comment: Hi @MatthewLeingang, thank you for the helpful comments. I included what I've tried so far to the original question.

Comment: A normed real vector space is a vector space $V$ over $\Bbb R$ with a function $f:V\to [0,\infty)$ such that (i) $f(v)=0$ iff $v=0, \; $(ii) $f(rv)=|r|f(v)$ when $r\in \Bbb R\;$ (iii) $f(u+v)\le f(u)+f(v).$ We usually write $\|u\|$ for $f(u).$  The formula for $u\cdot v$ in your Q will often NOT be linear in $u$ or $v$ and hence not distributive over $+$. Without more info about which vector space and which norm, we cannot proceed.

Comment: You have to assume the norm satisfies the parallelogram law. Even then, the claim is not obvious. See [Norms Induced by Inner Products and the Parallelogram Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/43848/568204).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet This just happens to be an exercise I came across in an undergraduate textbook on vectors and tensors. I can't quite tell whether the definitions given there would be sufficient for result to follow. There a vector was defined as the set of all arrows equivalent to a given arrow. An arrow was defined as an ordered pair of points, and two arrows were defined equivalent if one could be brought into coincidence with the other by a parallel translation. Finally, the length of a vector was defined as the length of any of its arrows.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for referencing that question. I noticed that Step 2 of the answer given by t.b. answers my question.