# Mock scalar product's nonlinearity as a derivation

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, normed-spaces, inner-products, derivations

**Context**. I was reading about the [converse of the parallelogram law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law) (a norm satisfying the law defines an inner product), and in an [answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/62035/508777) it is stated that this is impossible without the norm's inequality axiom (yielding continuity). Ivanov constructs an explicit counterexample, and makes a claim (below) which I am unable to verify.

**Definition**. A *mock scalar product* $\langle-,-\rangle$ on a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ satisfies

- homogeneity: $\langle tu,tv\rangle=t^2\langle u,v\rangle$
- symmetry: $\langle u,v\rangle=\langle v,u\rangle$
- biadditivity: $\langle u,v+v'\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle+\langle u,v'\rangle$

(Homogeneity is equivalent to $\langle tu,tu\rangle=t^2\langle u,u\rangle$ via polarization unless $\mathrm{char}\,\mathbb{F}=2$.)

**Claim**. $D_{u,v}(t):=\langle u,vt\rangle-\langle u,v\rangle t$ is a derivation of $t\in\mathbb{F}$ (for any $u,v\in V$).

(Recall a *derivation* $D$ satisfies $D(s+t)=D(s)+D(t)$ and $D(st)=D(s)t+sD(t)$ for any $s,t\in\mathbb{F}$. I wrote $t$ on the right of the $v$ only so $D_{u,v}$ looks more like an operator.)

**Question**. How do we verify the claim from the MO thread?

**Work**. Writing out the product rule for $D_{u,v}$, we could add $2\langle u,v\rangle st$ to both sides but I don't see how this helps. Presumably there is a way to move scalars around using homogeneity but I don't see it. When I use homogeneity to verify the special case $D_{u,v}(1/t)=-D_{u,v}(t)/t^2$ I instead get

$$ \begin{array}{cl}
D_{u,v}(1/t) & = \langle u,v/t\rangle-\langle u,v\rangle/t \\ 
& = \big(\langle tu,v\rangle-\langle u,v\rangle t\big)/t^2 \\
& = D_{v,u}(t)/t^2
\end{array} $$

When $u=v$ this seems to be the opposite of what it ought to be if $D_{u,v}$ is a derivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof assuming the characteristic is different from $2$.  For convenience of typing I will write $\langle u,v\rangle$ as $(u,v)$.  Note first that homogeneity with respect to the scalar $s+t$ gives $$(su,sv)+(su,tv)+(tu,sv)+(tu,tv)=(s^2+2st+t^2)(u,v)$$ and hence $$(su,tv)+(tu,sv)=2st(u,v). \quad(*)$$

(By the way, when $t=1$, this implies $D_{u,v}=-D_{v,u}$ so $D_{u,u}=0$ if the characteristic is different from $2$, which explains the computation that you did.)

Now the idea is to use $(*)$ repeatedly to see what you get for an expression like $(stu,v)$ where you multiply by $st$ inside the scalar product.  Two applications of $(*)$ gives $$(stu,v)+(su,tv)+2t(u,vs)=2t(su,v)+2t(u,sv)=4st(u,v).$$

Adding this equation to the same equation with $s$ and $t$ swapped gives $$2(stu,v)+(su,tv)+(tu,sv) + 2t(u,sv)+2s(u,tv)= 8st(u,v)$$ and combining this with $(*)$ and dividing by $2$ yields $$(stu,v)+t(u,sv)+s(u,tv)=3st(u,v).$$

Now applying $(*)$ with $st$ in place of $s$ and $1$ in place of $t$ gives $(stu,v)+(u,stv)=2st(u,v)$ so the equation above gives $$-st(u,v)+t(u,sv)+s(u,tv)=(u,stv).$$

Now note that $t(u,sv)=tD_{u,v}(s)-st(u,v)$, $s(u,tv)=sD_{u,v}(t)-st(u,v)$, and $(u,stv)=D_{u,v}(st)-st(u,v)$.  Thus adding $st(u,v)$ to both sides of the previous equation gives $$tD_{u,v}(s)+sD_{u,v}(t)=D_{u,v}(st).$$

---

On the other hand, here is a counterexample in characteristic $2$.  Let $V=\mathbb{F}$ be a field of characteristic $2$ and let $f:\mathbb{F}\to \mathbb{F}$ be an $\mathbb{F}^2$-linear map such that $f(1)=0$, and define $$(x,y)=f(xy).$$  This is a mock scalar product, with homogeneity following from the fact that $f$ is $\mathbb{F}^2$-linear.  The function $D_{1,1}$ is then just $f$, which need not be a derivation.  For instance, if $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{F}_2(x,y)$, then $1,x,y,$ and $xy$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}^2$, so $f$ can take arbitrary values on $x,y,$ and $xy$.

(Conversely, in characteristic $2$, $(*)$ implies that $(su,v)=(u,sv)$ so $(s^2u,v)=(su,sv)=s^2(u,v)$ and thus $D_{u,v}$ must be $\mathbb{F}^2$-linear.)

Comment: Interesting road one has to go down. When you get to the equ with the $3$, I notice subtracting $(stu,v)$ and $2st(u,v)$ from both sides yields $D_{u,v}(s)t+sD_{u,v}(t)=-D_{v,u}(st)$, which seems a tad more expedient. Took me a minute to realize $\Bbb F^2$ is literally the subfield of squares (closed under addition b/c Freshman's dream). Plus the converse makes it tight. Nice.