# How to define an inner product for normed space?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

> **Possible Duplicates:** 
>   [Norms Induced by Inner Products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products)
>   [From norm to scalar product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20379/from-norm-to-scalar-product)

Given a normed space $(X, \|\cdot\|)$. Is it possible to define an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on space $X$ based on the norm $\|\cdot\|$?

Comment: A better fit, including a sketch of the proof, is in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products

Comment: @Arturo: I've edited in your link.