# Linear Algebra: proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R^n$ are orthogonal if, and only if, $\|\alpha-\beta\|=\|\alpha+\beta\|$

My first thought was to square each side as to get rid of the square root, and then its just a dot product but for some reason I am not reaching the desired result.  Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean $n\times 1$ in exponent? Typeset as `$n\times 1$`. (But I think the more usual notation for vectors is $\mathbb R^n$.)

Comment: Maybe this (and related question) might help you: [From norm to scalar product](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20379/from-norm-to-scalar-product).

Answer (score 4):

Your first thought was correct. Square both side to get $\|\alpha-\beta\|=\|\alpha+\beta\|\iff \langle\alpha-\beta,\alpha-\beta\rangle=\langle\alpha+\beta,\alpha+\beta\rangle$.

Then use the bilinearity of the dot product to obtain $\langle\alpha-\beta,\alpha-\beta\rangle=\langle\alpha+\beta,\alpha+\beta\rangle\iff 4\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle=0.$

The last equation is equivalent to $\alpha,\beta$ being orthogonal.

Comment: ok i see i should of kept going,i just was not sure if that was the right track.  But since its an if and only if proof what is the other direction i need to go?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, I'm not sure what the problem is!

Since both sides are positive, it is equivalent to the same equation squared. But then we can expand both squares to get
$$ (x\pm y)\cdot(x\pm y) = x^2 +y^2 \pm 2 x\cdot y$$
Then take away the squared terms, and you're left with $4x\cdot y= 0$, your result.

Comment: ok that way makes sense, and once i did each dot product out i got the same result as you.  But what is the other direction i need to go in order to finish the proof.

Comment: The entire argument has $\iff$ symbols throughout it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe not that neat, but still: $ \|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2}$, $ \|\mathbf{x} +\mathbf{y}\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i + y_i)^2}$, square them $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i + y_i)^2$ or $$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i )^2+\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i)^2+2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i )^2+\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i)^2-2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$$ or $$4\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i=4\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}=0$$ which is exactly what you want.

Comment: I see the way you did it as well and it makes a lot of sense.  But since its and if and only if proof, what is the other direction i need to go in order to finish the proof.

Comment: @user74844 Well, you can reverse it. Say if $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $x$ and $y$ are orthigonal, then $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}=0$, so $4\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}=0$. Just add and subtract $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\cdot\mathbf{y}$ and reorganize the terms to get what you want.

Comment: oh i see so fairly straight forward

Answer (score 0):

We'll prove it for non-zero $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (the claim is straightforward otherwise).

We resolve $\beta$ into components $\beta^{\mathrm{para}}$ parallel to $\alpha$ and $\beta^{\mathrm{perp}}$ orthogonal to $\alpha$ (see the [vector projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) page on Wikipedia for details).  This is depicted below:

[image: Resolving $\beta$ into $\beta^{\mathrm{para}}$ parallel to $\alpha$ and $\beta^{\mathrm{perp}}$ orthogonal to $\alpha$]

Then
\begin{align*}
||\alpha+\beta|| &= ||\alpha+\beta^{\mathrm{para}}+\beta^{\mathrm{perp}}|| \\
 &= \sqrt{||\alpha+\beta^{\mathrm{para}}||^2+||\beta^{\mathrm{perp}}||^2}
\end{align*}
by Pythagoras' Theorem, since $\alpha+\beta^{\mathrm{para}}$ and $\beta^{\mathrm{perp}}$ are orthogonal.  Similarly
\begin{align*}
||\alpha-\beta|| &= ||\alpha-\beta^{\mathrm{para}}-\beta^{\mathrm{perp}}|| \\
 &= \sqrt{||\alpha-\beta^{\mathrm{para}}||^2+||\beta^{\mathrm{perp}}||^2}.
\end{align*}
This is depicted below:

[image: Identifying $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha-\beta$ in terms of $\alpha$, $\beta^{\mathrm{para}}$ and $\beta^{\mathrm{perp}}$]

Hence $||\alpha+\beta||=||\alpha-\beta||$ if and only if $$||\alpha+\beta^{\mathrm{para}}||=||\alpha-\beta^{\mathrm{para}}||$$
which happens if and only if $\beta^{\mathrm{para}}$ is the zero vector (since $\alpha$ is non-zero).  This happens if and only if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are orthogonal.