# Statement: “Consider vectors $u, v \in \Bbb R_n$. If $\Vert u−v \Vert = \Vert u+v \Vert$, then $u$ is orthogonal to $v$. Prove true or false."

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I attached my proof below and I am curious if there is any truth to it.[my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyvcS.jpg)

Comment: Please don't use pictures for text or formulas.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I didn't check your solution's validity, but it looks overly complicated. Hint: all you need is $\vec a \cdot \vec a = |\vec a|^2$.

Comment: I know the correct solution at this point, I am asking as it was an exam question, and I am curious if that answer has any validity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does "$u$ is orthogonal" mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear Algebra: proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375293/linear-algebra-proof)

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question!

Answer (score 1):

We have $\|u-v\|=\|u+v\|$ iff
$$\|u\|^2-2\langle u,v\rangle+\|v\|^2
=\|u\|^2+2\langle u,v\rangle+\|v\|^2$$
iff $\langle u,v\rangle=0$.  Avoid coordinate whenever possible.